# Linux found preloaded shared library: potential threat to security?

Tags: linux, security, raspbian

On a Linux Raspbian system, I have performed variuos security checks and among those I have performed a rkhunter scan to seek for rootkits, backdoors, and other malicious software with the following warning:

Warning: Found preloaded shared library: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so

Potentially this is a shared library providing a way to access and manage memory on the ARM platform, such as system-level memory management and may get access to critical system resources.

As far I can understand preloaded shared library pose a security risk, meaning that it has the full access to user data, system resources, and user privileges and could be potentially manipulated to gain access to secure information or resources.

I have searched for a specific documentation on such preloaded shared library, but I am not able to find any documentation about it.

I am seeking the documentation of such preloaded shared library to better understand if it poses a security issue.

I have reviewed the Stackoverflow posts and none answer my question.

Any support is much appreciated.

Comment: this should be moved to superuser.com

Comment: Thanks Sir for your comment, since this is a potential security issue on widely used systems, I would keep the question on StackOverflow as well.

Comment: stackoverflow is for code / programming, superuser is for this exact question

Comment: Thanks again, as a programmer I am interested also in security issues to write safe code, therefore I will keep the question on Stackoverflow as well since the subject can be of interest for others. Thanks for the suggestion to expand the question to SU also.